# create a test entry point in webpack react application

Tags: reactjs, webpack

**tldr**: I'm able to `require` everything to make the app run, but if I `require` modules from within a test (which is in the app - see dir structure below) file, the whole dependency chain breaks.

I'm having some difficulty `require`-ing components from my `app/test` directory (in my webpack React.js application) below that I have no difficulty `require` -ing from any other file in the `/app` folder. This is the directory structure

```
app
  /components/checkout.jsx
  /components/button.jsx
  /test/test.js 
  index.jsx  
dist
node_modules
webpack.config.js
package.json
```

in my webpack.config.js, I have it setup to use the jsx-loader for my React application like this

```js
entry: {
   app: "./app/index"
},
module: {
   loaders: [
        {
             test: /\.jsx$/,
             loader: 'jsx-loader?insertPragma=React.DOM&harmony',
     }
  ]
},
resolve: {
 extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
}
```

This allows me to require files ending in extension .jsx. For example, in `/app/index.jsx` I require `/app/components/checkout.jsx` by doing

```js
 var Checkout = require('./components/Checkout')
```

And inside `/app/components/checkout.jsx`, I require the button

```js
var Button = require('./components/Button')
```

so when I require the `Checkout` from the index.jsx, it handles the require of the Button without any problem.

However, from app/test/test.js, I do

```js
var Checkout = require('../components/Checkout')
```

and webpack cannot find the Checkout component. When I view the tests in the webpack dev server, it doesn't show that the .jsx file extension was looked for. It searched

```
 app/components/Checkout
 app/components/Checkout.webpack.js
 app/components/Checkout.web.js
 app/components/Checkout.js
 app/components/Checkout.json
```

Therefore, I tried to use the `jsx-loader`inline like this

```js
 var Checkout = require(jsx-loader!'../components/Checkout')
```

from the test directory, and webpack can now find the file, but it throws an error saying that it cannot resolve the Button that Checkout `requires`. In other words, when I use the `require` from within the `app/test` folder, the whole dependency chain is thrown out of sync.

How can I change my webpack.config.js to be able to require application files in my tests with this directory structure, or, more generally, how to configure webpack to require an application file in a test?

Update

Project structure

```
/app
  /test/test.js
  /index.jsx
  /components/checkout.jsx (and button.jsx)
/dist
/node_modules
package.json
webpack.config.js
```

whole webpack config

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + "/app",
    entry: {
      vendors: ["d3", "jquery"],
      app: "index"
      // app: "./app/index"

      },
    output: {
        path: './dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js', //this is the default name, so you can skip it
        //at this directory our bundle file will be available
        //make sure port 8090 is used when launching webpack-dev-server
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8090/assets/'
    },

    externals: {
        //don't bundle the 'react' npm package with our bundle.js
        //but get it from a global 'React' variable

        'react': 'React'
        // 'd3': 'd3'
    },
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['app', 'node_modules'],
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
        resolveLoader: { fallback: __dirname + "/node_modules" },
        root: ['/app', '/test']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
              test: /\.jsx$/, 
              loader: 'jsx-loader?insertPragma=React.DOM&harmony',
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
    // definePlugin,
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendors', 'vendors.js')

    ]
}
```

Comment: how did you setup webpack config to run the tests, is it the same or the separate from main? in my setup I am using 2 different configs to run dev builds and react tests. The fix for similar issue was to add resolve: { extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'] } in webpack for running tests.

Comment: @EugeneSafronov right now I only have one webpack config at the top level of the project. I put a copy of it in the update section of the OP, as well as more detail about the project structure.  I thought about using a second config for tests, but didn't know where to put it or how to configure it. Can you provide some info about that?

Comment: aren't you missing `include: __dirname` in your loaders? also try: `/\.jsx?$/`

Comment: @knowbody neither of those suggestions fix the problem.

Comment: @Leahcim I'll have a look at it once I'm on my laptop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution would be to **always** require with file extension:

```js
var Checkout = require('./components/Checkout.jsx')
```

Comment: that allows me to require that component in particular, but when running the test it says that that JSX tokens, (i.e. the `<`) are 'unexpected' .  the app still works properly, just the problem with the test. As I state in the OP `, when I use the require from within the app/test folder, the whole dependency chain is thrown out of sync.` in the OP `, so I think the problem is somehow related to my webpack.config.js file, relevant bits of which I show in the OP

Answer (score 3):

I guess it may be cuz of setting "test" as a root directory. But it isn't clear untill you share your code. Can you gimme a link to GitHub repo or something?

Comment: the test entry point was taken out (see the update to the OP). The project isn't on github.

Comment: I'm talking about this: root: ['/app', '/test'], its still exists in your webpack config

Answer (score 3):

i see you are using the harmony parameter, can i assume u are using, es6?

If so i had this problem before, the problem for me was that the files where added, as es6 without beeing transformed, to es5 by jsx-loader / babel-loader.

so i needed to add:

```
preLoaders: [{
    test: [/\.jsx$/, /\.js$/],
    include: // modules here
    loaders: ['babel-loader?optional[]=runtime']
}]
```

but then it would not explain why this only fails for your tests. maybe u can elaborate on what is runned when u run your tests
but for now im still under the assumption of you using es6,

if the above situation is not the case for you, try installing a local version of webpack, and look for it in your local dir, also for your app folder

```
(resolveLoader: { root: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules") })
```

hope this helps

edit: ps looking at your config, resolveLoader should not be a part of your resolve, in another webpack setup i use, i have the following setup
for resolving:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
  modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'node_modules/vl_tooling/node_modules']
},
resolveLoader: {
  modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'node_modules/vl_tooling/node_modules']
},
```

Comment: I'm using jsx but not es6. At the end of your answer, you put `modulesDirectories' in both 'resolve' and 'resolveLoader'. Should it be in both?

Answer (score 1):

I setup separate gulp task to run React tests, maybe you could reuse the idea:

karma.js

```js
var karma = require('gulp-karma'),
  _ = require('lodash'),
  Promise = require('bluebird'),
  plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
  path = require('path'),
  webpack = require('gulp-webpack'),
  named = require('vinyl-named');

module.exports = function (gulp, options) {
  var root = path.join(options.cwd, 'app'),
    extensions = ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    modulesDirectories = ['node_modules'];

  gulp.task('karma', ['karma:build'], function () {
    return runAllTests(gulp, options);
  });

  gulp.task('karma:build', function() {
    var optionsForTests = _.merge({
      ignore: ['**/node_modules/**']
    }, options);

    return gulp.src(['**/__tests__/*.js'], optionsForTests).
      pipe(named(function(file){
        // name file bundle.js
        return 'bundle';
      })).
      pipe(webpack({
        module: {
          loaders: [
              // runtime option adds Object.assign support
              { test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, loader: 'babel-loader?optional[]=runtime', exclude: /node_modules/},
              { test: /\.(sass|scss)$/, loader: 'css-loader!sass-loader'},
              { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'url-loader'},
              { test: /\.(ttf|eot)$/, loader: 'file-loader'},
              { test: /sinon.*\.js$/, loader: 'imports?define=>false' } // hack due to https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/304
          ]
        },
        resolve: {
          root: root,
          extensions: extensions,
          modulesDirectories: modulesDirectories
        }
      })).
      pipe(gulp.dest('test-build'));
  })

}

function runAllTests(gulp, options) {
  var optionsForTests = _.merge({
    ignore: ['**/node_modules/**']
  }, options);

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var karmaConfig = path.join(path.resolve(__dirname, '..'), 'karma.conf.js');

    // shim Prototype.function.bind in PhantomJS 1.x
    var testFiles = [
      'node_modules/es5-shim/es5-shim.min.js',
      'node_modules/es5-shim/es5-sham.min.js',
      'test-build/bundle.js'];

    gulp.src(testFiles).
      pipe(plumber({
        errorHandler: function (error) {
          console.log(error);
          this.emit('end');
        }
      })).
      pipe(karma({
        configFile: karmaConfig,
        action: 'run'
      })).
      on('end', function () { resolve(); });
  });
}
```

Gulp file:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var auctionataBuild = require('auctionata-build');
var path = require('path');

auctionataBuild.tasks.karma(gulp, {
  cwd: path.resolve(__dirname)
});
```

Run from terminal:

```
 gulp karma
```